# app does not show login page even when user isn't signed in

Tags: swift, firebase

So i want my app to be able to detect if the user is logged in, I've implemented firebase authentication and the setup and login functions all in alr. When the app launches, it goes to the home page, and its supposed to segue to the login page from there if it detects that there isn't any user logged in. But for some reason even when there aren't any users logged in,the app still doesn't perform the segue!code for home page is below

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore

class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ExerciseBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ExerciseData: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var shopbtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var leaderboardbtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var profilebtn: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ExerciseBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        ExerciseData.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        shopbtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        leaderboardbtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        profilebtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        ExerciseData.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "data"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        shopbtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "shop"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        leaderboardbtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "leaderboard"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        profilebtn.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "profile"), for: UIControl.State.normal)

        if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "notlogin", sender: self)
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    

    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Comment: Have you verified that currentUser is nil as you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

nvm i found a way that would work, instead of checking if the currentuser is nil or not, I just used `Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener` instead as it would run only after app initilization was done.